# Prefix a hanging indent with a character?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I'm formatting some VBA code for reading, and obviously a lot of the lines flow to the next line. I've applied a hanging indent to make it clear that it's a continuation of the previous line, but I'd like to put a prefix on it (Wingdings 3: 57[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OybiE.png) or similar, perhaps) to make it clear.

Is there any way to do that automatically, either through formatting or VBA, or would I have to just go through and do it all manually?

Answer (score 0):

In your document, insert your symbol once, select it and copy it.  Then you can delete the symbol.

Then just do a simple find and replace.

In the Find what:  ^p (this will find each paragraph mark).

In the Replace with: box ^p^c (including a space after the c)

This will replace each paragraph mark with paragraph mark then your symbol (as you copied it to clipboard) then a space.  So you will end up with the symbol at the start of each new paragraph.

Comment: That's what I'd do if I wanted on the first line of a paragraph, but I'm looking for a way to indicate that a line is a continuation of a paragraph - essentially what you suggested but with the wrapping breaks instead.